# How to tuning HTTPClient performance in crawling large amount small files?

Tags: java, web-crawler, httpclient

I just want to crawl some Hacker News Stories, and my code:

```
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class HackCrawler {
    private static String getUrlResponse(String url) throws IOException {
        return Request.Get(url).execute().returnContent().asString();
    }

    private static String crawlItem(int id) {
        try {
            String json = getUrlResponse(String.format("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/%d.json", id));
            if (json.contains("\"type\":\"story\"")) {
                return json;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("crawl " + id + " failed");
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("main");
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("hack.json");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            logger.info("batch " + i);
            IntStream.range(12530671 - (i + 1) * 100, 12530671 - i * 100)
                    .parallel()
                    .mapToObj(HackCrawler::crawlItem).filter(x -> !x.equals(""))
                    .forEach(printWriter::println);
        }
    }
}
```

Now it will cost 3 seconds to crawl 100(1 batch) items.

I found use multithreading by `parallel` will give a speed up (about 5 times), but I have no idea about how to optimise it further.

Could any one give some suggestion about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what Fayaz means I would use Jetty Http Client asynchronous features (https://webtide.com/the-new-jetty-9-http-client/).

```
httpClient.newRequest("http://domain.com/path")
        .send(new Response.CompleteListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Result result)
            {
                // Your logic here
            }
        });
```

This client internally uses Java NIO to listen for incoming responses with a single thread per connection. It then dispatches content to worker threads which are not involved in any blocking I/O operation.

You can try to play with the maximum number of connections per destination (a destination is basically an host)

http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.11.v20160721/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpClient.html#setMaxConnectionsPerDestination-int-

Since you are heavily loading a single server, this should be quite high.

Comment: I have checked the documentation of Jetty HttpClient, but I can't find any thing about connection management(I think `keep-alive` will improve the performance), do you have any idea about that?

Comment: in HTTP 1.1 connections are persistent by default

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should get you started.

1. Use a single thread to get response from the site as this is basically an IO operation.
2. Put these responses into a queue(Read about various implementations of BlockingQueue)
3. Now you can have multiple threads to pick up these responses and process them as you wish.

Basically, you will be having a single producer thread that gets the responses from the sites and multiple consumers who process these responses.

Comment: But I have tried multithreading by `parallel()`... Does multithreading by a BlockingQueue will improving performance magically?

Comment: In your approach, you are spawning multiple threads and each of them are doing both the tasks of getting the response and processing them. I don't think that is the recommended approach. Your is a case of typical producer consumer problem.